# iOS:CRC in obj c

Tags: objective-c, iphone, crc32

i am new to iOS i need to  create data packet by using CRC algorithm for the below commands

```
 int comm[6];
 comm[0]=0x01;
 comm[1]=6;
 comm[2]=0x70;
 comm[3]=0x00;
 comm[4]=0xFFFF;
 comm[5]=0xFFFF;
```

i had a java code which as same thing developing in android

```
         byte[] getCRC(byte[] bytes)
         {
            byte[] result = new byte[2];
            try
            {
                        short crc = (short) 0xFFFF;
                        for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++)
                        {
                               byte c = bytes[j];
                                for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
                                 {
                                    boolean c15 = ((crc >> 15 & 1) == 1)
                                    boolean bit = ((c >> (7 - i) & 1) == 1);
                                    crc <<= 1;
                                    if (c15 ^ bit)
                                    {
                                 crc ^=  0x1021; // 0001 0000 0010 0001 (0, 5, 12)

       }
                                            }
                            }
                            int crc2 = crc - 0xffff0000;
                            result[0] = (byte) (crc2 % 256);
                            result[1] = (byte) (crc2 / 256);


            return result;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                            result = null;
                            return result;
            }

         }
```

Input for getCRC() method:        The data packet for which CRC is to be calculated.

Output of getCRC() method:      CRC for the packet.

The same thing i need to do in obj c please help if any sample code available also.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C also incorporates C, so the contents of your method will look almost the same as in Java. All that is needed is to pass your data into and out of the method, in this example using NSData:

```
- (NSData *)bytesCRCResult:(NSData *)dataBytes
{
    unsigned char *result = (unsigned char *)malloc(2);
    unsigned char *bytes = (unsigned char *)[dataBytes bytes]; // returns readonly pointer to the byte stream

    uint16_t crc = (short) 0xFFFF;
    for (int j = 0; j < dataBytes.length; j++)
    {
        unsigned char c = bytes[j];
        for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            bool c15 = ((crc >> 15 & 1) == 1);
            bool bit = ((c >> (7 - i) & 1) == 1);
            crc <<= 1;
            if (c15 ^ bit)
            {
                crc ^=  0x1021; // 0001 0000 0010 0001 (0, 5, 12)
            }
        }
    }

    uint16_t crc2 = crc - 0xffff0000;
    result[0] = (unsigned char) (crc2 % 256);
    result[1] = (unsigned char) (crc2 / 256);

    NSData *resultsToData = [NSData dataWithBytes:result length:2];
    free(result);
    return resultsToData;  
}
```

NSData can be read as raw bytes using the [NSData bytes] method call, and has a range of useful properties and methods.

For the boolean value, you have a few options:

- "bool" seems to be the ISO C/C++ standard type
- "Boolean" is defined as "typedef unsigned char"
- "boolean_t" is defined as "typedef unsigned int" or "typedef int", depending on 64-bit compilation apparently
- "BOOL", the Objective-C bool, which is defined as "typedef signed char", according to http://nshipster.com/bool/ and might therefore not behave as expected.

"uint8_t" can be substituted for "unsigned char", for clarity.

Please note: The above code compiles without warning or complaint, but wasn't tested with actual data.